# Pycharm importerror: cannot import name '_backcompat_magic_number'

Tags: python, python-3.5

When I start **pycharm** it shows an error while configuring interpreter. plz help..

> ERROR:- importerror: cannot import name '_backcompat_magic_number'

Comment: Possible answer: [ImportError: cannot import name '_BACKCOMPAT_MAGIC_NUMBER'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50115085/6890912)