# Django site fails with "ImportError: cannot import name '_BACKCOMPAT_MAGIC_NUMBER'" after working fine for months

Tags: python, django

I have Django app on hosting which has been running since June last year. I forgot to buy credits and so my hosting provider freezed my app. I bought new credits but I does not start. I simply get: "502 Bad Gateway".

I checked the logs, and in `python.log` found possible problem. Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/srv/venv/bin/gunicorn", line 7, in <module>
    from gunicorn.app.wsgiapp import run
  File "/srv/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 10, in <module>
    from gunicorn.app.base import Application
  File "/srv/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 12, in <module>
    from gunicorn import util
  File "/srv/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 12, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "/srv/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    import zipfile
  File "/opt/python/lib/python3.5/zipfile.py", line 9, in <module>
    import importlib.util
  File "/srv/venv/lib/python3.5/importlib/util.py", line 7, in <module>
    from ._bootstrap_external import MAGIC_NUMBER, _BACKCOMPAT_MAGIC_NUMBER
ImportError: cannot import name '_BACKCOMPAT_MAGIC_NUMBER'
```

As far as I know there weren't any changes prior to this problem. Moreover I cannot find similar issues here on SO or elsewhere on the net.

`importlib` should be part of Python 3 so I thought I could try commenting out the import from `"/opt/python/lib/python3.5/zipfile.py"` but I don't have write permissions on the server.

I also tried recreating the venv which did not help. Same with switching Python runtime to either 3.4 or 3.6 in hosting's administration.

Comment: are you sure you 'rm -rf' your venv, reinstall it and that didn't help?

Comment: @DmitriiG. yes, whole venv folder is brand new

Comment: Related: [ImportError: cannot import name '_BACKCOMPAT_MAGIC_NUMBER'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48000502/95735)