# django channels install error

Tags: django, python-3.5, django-channels

I am trying to create a one to one real-time messaging system using Django. Upon searching I found out about `django-channels`. So i created a virtual env with python 3.5 and latest Django but when I do `pip install channels` I get :

```
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.5m -I/home/kshitij/Documents/projects/personal/maker/venv/include/python3.5m -c src/twisted/test/raiser.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.5/src/twisted/test/raiser.o

 #include "Python.h"
                    ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

probably because of missing python headers so i did : `sudo apt-get install python3-dev` but it still shows the same error. What should I do?

```
pip version:    18
python version: 3.5
django version: 2.1
```

I tried doing `sudo apt-get install python3-dev` but getting:

```
 ImportError: cannot import name '_BACKCOMPAT_MAGIC_NUMBER'
```

Comment: Did you find the solution buddy? Can you please tell the community how did you fix? That will help others and save their time.

Comment: @KishorPawar the solution that you said was what i had follwed myself and it worked. i have acepted your answer so that it helps others in future

Comment: I am glad my solution helped. I think you just upvoted the answer and not accepted.

Comment: @KishorPawar my bad,missed that.should be done now :)

Comment: What was the actual problem? Pip or dev?

Comment: initially i had installed `python3-dev` so i was getting the error  instead it should have `python3.5-dev` once i installed this and recreated a virtualenv with `pip3` it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Verify your `pip` is not `pip` and its `pip3`.
2. You may also try installing `sudo apt install python3.X-dev`.

For you, it's `sudo apt install python3.5-dev`

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the Linux compiler and `python3-dev`:

```sh
sudo apt install gcc
sudo apt install python3-dev
pip install channels
```

Answer (score 0):

The last error may indicates you have an issue caused by many python versions installed on your system (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50115085/1887976)). You should make sure you don't have incomplete or corrupted python installation on your system (did you already compiled Python by yourself?). In addition, make sure the package `python3` is correctly installed or `sudo apt-get install python3-dev` cannot succeed.

In addition, you may try to locate `Python.h` on your system. Make sure each `Python.h` on your system correspond to a valid python setup (you may have one for python 2 and one more for python 3).